# Filtering White Space from String in powershell

Tags: powershell, parsing, variables, whitespace

I am trying to filter a file name down for example, what i want to do is filter to the underscore and leave the rest.
Info10_ComputerHostName
so i run

```
$FileName="Info10_ComputerHostName"
$FinalFileName = $FileName -split("*._")
```

When i output the variable what i get
" ComputerHostName"

What I want
"ComputerHostName"

How do I remove the whitespace that it always returns?

Comment: Try `$FinalFileName = ($FileName -split '_')[1]`

Comment: I get a syntax error.

Comment: your split target is ... very peculiar. [*grin*] replace it with the bare underscore & array index as shown by `Theo` to get what you appear to want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$FinalFileName = ([regex]::Match($FileName,'([^_]*)_(.*)'))
$FinalFileName.Groups[2].Value

#or

$FileName.Split('_')[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$FinalFileName[1]`. Proof:

```
$FileName="Info10_ComputerHostName"
$FinalFileName = $FileName -split ".*_"
$FinalFileName.GetType().FullName
$FinalFileName.Count
"`$FinalFileName   ='$FinalFileName'"
"`$FinalFileName[0]='$($FinalFileName[0])'"
"`$FinalFileName[1]='$($FinalFileName[1])'"
```

> ```
> System.String[]
> 2
> $FinalFileName   =' ComputerHostName'
> $FinalFileName[0]=''
> $FinalFileName[1]='ComputerHostName'
> ```

Another approach - use `-replace` operator instead of `-split` as follows:

```
$FileName="Info10_ComputerHostName"
$FinalFileName = $FileName -replace "^.*?_"
$FinalFileName.GetType().FullName
"`$FinalFileName   ='$FinalFileName'"
```

> ```
> System.String
> $FinalFileName   ='ComputerHostName'
> ```